# Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied

Tags: php, text-files

i have this php function to read my dbinfo out of a textfile on my pc:

```
function loaddb(){
    $fh = fopen('dta.txt','r');
        $line = fgets($fh);
        $_SESSION['dbname']=$line;
        
        $line = fgets($fh);
        $_SESSION['dbuser']=$line;
        
        $line = fgets($fh);
        $_SESSION['dbpass']=$line;
        
        $line = fgets($fh);
        $_SESSION['server']=$line;                                  
    fclose($fh);
};
```

and this code works. but when it returns my code into my session var i see it has added extra line breaks in the actual variable, so the result when i connect is

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root
>
> '@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
> C:\Users\Jacques\Dropbox\Jacques\Web\Code.php on line 37 Could not
> connect: Access denied for user 'root
>
> '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

how can i fix this. i have tried replacing all character return and spaces but it doesnt help

this is the text in my textfile

> dbname
>
> root
>
> password
>
> localhost:3306

Comment: Read the reference on [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) - youll see that the newlines are included in the returned string. Either `trim()` them, or use `file()` to read the file into an array, and set the flag to discard newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the whitespaces are on each end of the string, you can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$_SESSION['dbname']= trim($line);
```

When you're dealign with a string that can have several spaces, you can solve that with a simple regular expression:

```
$regex = '/(\s)\s+/'; // Select a whitespace and following whitespaces
$str = preg_replace($regex, '$1', $str); // Replace with the first whitespace
```

---

## Important sidenote

Saving your database credentials in a text file in your www folder is a very bad practise. If someone happens to find the filename he can read your credentials.

PHP code however is parsed before sent to the client, thus client's can't access the credentials (unless you echo them).

**config.php**

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
```

Then, whenever you need your database credentials:

```
require 'config.php';
// connect here
```

---

### Another sidenote

The [mysql_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. You should use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. I prefer PDO myself.

Comment: what is the main difference beween pdo and mysqli_

Comment: `mysqli_` is an extended version of `mysql_`. You will find that they are very similar. PDO is only an interface for database connections. I like it a lot because it's OOP oriented. Apart from that is no major difference. Both will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check like this :

```
$_SESSION['dbname'] = trim($line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim()`:

```
$_SESSION['dbname']= trim($line);
```

From the docs:

"This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:"

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
- **"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.**
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php